# The name 'i' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an inventory in unity and I have a part of a script that makes the slot not full when it is empty, but I just get this error message.
here is my first script(the error is in this)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour
{

  private InventoryTest InventoryTest;
    public void DropItem ()
    {
     foreach (Transform child in transform)
  {
    child.GetComponent<Spawn>().SpawnDroppedItem();
      GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
  }
}
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    InventoryTest = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<InventoryTest>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (transform.childCount <= 0) {
      InventoryTest.isfull[i] = false;
    }
    }
}
```

and here is my second script(this just makes the isfull and stuff

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InventoryTest : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool[] isfull;
public GameObject[] slots;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
```

}

Comment: In the first Update function: ``InventoryTest.isfull[i] = false;`` 'i' is not defined.

Comment: Nobody ever tries to read exception messages :( _"The name 'i' does not exist in the current context"_ means that there is no `i` in the context of current method call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is this line

```
InventoryTest.isfull[i] = false;
```

You have not defined "i". You might be missing a for loop.